# Second monitor prevents booting on 20.04 (onboard graphics)

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I am running an (almost) fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04, all latest updates applied. I completed the process on an HDMI monitor that was plugged into the motherboard (a [ROG STRIX B560-F GAMING WIFI](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b560-f-gaming-wifi-model/)). It is running on an onboard GPU on an i5-11600k – the computer doesn't have a graphics card.

Everything worked fine until I plugged in my second monitor via DP. It's supposed to mirror/duplicate the 1920x1080x60 display (which worked perfectly fine on a previous system, the two monitors are completely compatible). When I try to boot the system with *both* monitors plugged in, I run into a problem: not even the Kubuntu logo shows up on boot, I end up on two black screens and the LED on the tower is showing no activity. I have to force a shutdown via the power button.

When I unplug the DP monitor and only boot into the HDMI, it works completely fine as it should. Plugging the DP monitor in, when the system is already running, makes it work almost instantly (after a short black flash) and I can customize everything I want. I can even suspend to RAM, log out, log back in, etc. Until the next reboot, then I end up on two black screens again. Only a hard reset after pulling the DP plug works.

I enabled "iGPU Multi-Monitor" in the BIOS, [as described in the MoBo FAQs](https://rog.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045574), but it didn't solve the problem.

You probably need more system info from me. Ask away, I will provide any info I can.

Thanks so much in advance.

`lspci | grep VGA`
returned:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)`

`sudo lshw -C video`
returned:

````
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:141 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff ```
````

Comment: Have you confirmed with the manufacture that you can have monitors on both the DP and HDMI and it is fully supported?

Comment: The motherboard is this one: [ROG STRIX B560-F GAMING WIFI](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b560-f-gaming-wifi-model/). The website says: "Supports HDMI™ 2.0 and DisplayPort 1.4 output", and under "Tech Spechs" it mentions nothing that would go against it. At least I think so.

Comment: I will try again but it does not say both at once? Any way based on my own personal experience that is my thoughts.

Comment: @David , no, it doesn't say that specifically, it only says: "Graphics specifications may vary between CPU types.", the rest is about higher resolutions than I am using. As I said, it's running perfectly fine when I plug in the DP while I'm already logged into the desktop. I can do pretty much everything I want then, the problem is only when booting.

Comment: I tried to enable "iGPU multi-monitor" in the BIOS as described [in the FAQ here](https://rog.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045574), but it didn't work. It seems to be enabled, but doesn't fix the black screens on boot.

Comment: (1) Update UEFI (2) make sure you're running at least the 5.13 kernel, preferably a newer Ubuntu release like 21.10.